# Using all Metropolis-Hastings proposals to estimate an integral

Tags: mathematical-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings, rao-blackwell

Suppose we run the Metropolis-Hastings with target distribution $\mu$ to compute the integral $\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$. Usually, we use the estimator $$A_n:=\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i).$$ However, instead of adding up the $f(X_i)$, I've seen the following modification: Let $(Y_n)_n$ denote the sequence of proposals. By definition, $Y_i$ is accepted and $X_i$ is set to $Y_i$ with probability $\alpha(X_{i-1},X_i)$. Instead of adding $f(X_i)$ to the sum, we could add $(1-\alpha(X_{i-1},Y_i))f(X_{i-1})+\alpha(X_{i-1},Y_i)f(Y_i)$.

I couldn't find any lecture book or paper considering this modification or an estimator modified in a similar way (except this [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Using-all-Metropolis-Hastings-proposals-to-estimate-Tjelmeland/d66b766d44e6b50732f30e97cec5aff3312bc28f)). Does anybody have a reference at hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]Recycling proposed values in a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm goes under the name of [Rao-Blackwellisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/223952/7224). For instance, we made such a proposal in

- Casella and Robert (1996) [Rao-Blackwellisation of sampling schemes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2337434?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).
- Douc and Robert (2013) [A vanilla Rao-Blackwellisation of Metropolis-Hastings algorithms](https://www.jstor.org/stable/29783637?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Note that the weighting you propose in the question:
$$[1-\alpha(x_i,y_{i+1})]h(x_i)+\alpha(x_i,y_{i+1})h(y_i)$$
is not optimal in that it is not guaranteed to bring the variance down. Even the one I produce [above] in one of my MCMC course slides does not always reduce the variance because of the correlation between the different terms. (Only the data augmentation case leads to a sure reduction in the variance, cf this fantastic paper by [Liu, Wong and Long, 1994](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2337047?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). And [vanilla Rao-Blackwellisation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/29783637?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check the papers and accept your answer soon. Just one quick question: Is the process $(X_{n-1},Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ again a Markov process? If I'm not missing anything, this should be the case.

Comment: Yes indeed, the joint chain is a Markov chain, either $(_{−1},_)_{∈ℕ}$ or $(_{},_)_{∈ℕ}$.

Comment: Can we give an expression for the transition kernel? Assuming that $(X_{n-1},Y_n)\sim\mathcal L(X_{n-1})\otimes Q$, where $Q$ is the proposal kernel?

Comment: The usual transition on $X_{n-1}$ given $Y_{n-1}$ and $X_{n-2}$ times the proposal.

Comment: Took me a while to determine the transition kernel, but now I've obtained $$\operatorname P\left[(X_n,Y_{n+1})\in A_n\times B_{n+1}\mid(X_{n-1},Y_n)\right]=\delta_{Y_n}\alpha(X_{n-1},Y_n)Q(Y_n,B_{n+1})+\delta_{X_{n-1}}(A_n)(1-\alpha(X_{n-1},Y_n))Q(X_{n-1},B_{n+1}).$$ Is that what you've got in mind?

Answer (score 5):

This looks similar to "local" importance sampling. In the literature, constructing estimators of this sort seem to termed as "waste-recyling", and quick search yields a few papers:

- [This thesis by Murray](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/imurray2/pub/07thesis/murray_thesis_2007.pdf)
- PNAS paper by Freknel [here](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/101/51/17571.full.pdf)
- Does waste-recyling help by Delmas and Jourdain [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611949.pdf)
- Their use in parallel MCMC [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11222-017-9780-4.pdf)

Further search using the keyword "waste-recyling" and look within the above references might give you some more papers.